# Lumen deployment error on Heroku / Scalingo

Tags: laravel, heroku, deployment, composer-php, lumen

I created a fresh lumen project using composer and try to put it on heroku/scalingo.

However in both hosting solutions I get the following error:

```
Generating optimized autoload files

  [RuntimeException]                                                                                                                                                         
  Could not scan for classes inside "/build/4a8cf965dc0068e76480b81aa5321cff/vendor/laravel/lumen-framework/src/Foundation" which does not appear to be a file nor a folder
```

It is related to composer but I dont understand how.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added to exclude the /vendor/ folder on .gitignore and this solved the problem. But I dont understand what it was looking for that broke it.